# Writing a Schengen invitation letter, for Spain from the UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

There's a conference happing in Spain in late April for the main software stack for $DAYJOB, to which I'll be heading. As a UK national, that's no issue visa-wise. Work have just OK'd the budget for me to bring one of my team from India to the event too, which means I'll need to help them with getting a Schengen visa.

My company doesn't have any offices or presence in Spain. The costs for the trip (flights, hotels, conference fee, food etc) will be covered (for various reasons) by the UK part of the business for both of us. I believe, therefore, that my Indian colleague needs some sort of invitation letter confirming that all their costs will be covered for them by the company.

I've asked around the office, but the only Schengen visa invitation letters they have are for Indians visiting our Warsaw office, which are written in Polish so not that much help here, especially as I can't read Polish....

Is there any guidance on what I should be putting into the invitation letter? Such as who it needs to be addressed to, what it needs to say about my Indian colleague, what it needs to say about the funding etc?

Otherwise, I'm guessing the letter wants to be printed on company headed paper and signed by someone suitably senior from the UK head office. What about the language though - can it be in English, or do I need to dust off my Spanish dictionary and then invite a Spanish friend over for beer + to help me write it?

Comment: Just a quick comment; [for short-term visas, translations are not requested](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/spain-visa/) nor should s/he require an invitation. It would seem that leave permission from your company that includes the reason for travel should do it.

Comment: English is fine, definitely on letterhead, addressed to **the consular officer**, some blurbs about the candidate and his importance to the firm and why his particular attendance is important, definitely about who is funding. If you're a huge international prestigious firm, I don't know if bank statements would be required. He should have his though because he is also being evaluated.

Comment: My friend once invited me from Switzerland and he wrote in English and didn't use either German or French. Assuming Spanish visa officers are reasonable English should do the trick.

Comment: The visa application will be submitted in India, where English is the language of business. English should be fine.

Comment: You can address it to the "Secretario de Embajada de segunda clase" or "Cónsul de Segunda Clase"  any similar title as long as it specifies someone junior to the Consul-General

Answer (score 2):

> [Schengen Visa Information](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/spain-visa/) gives a handy checklist of what is required. Note the three specifics that, rather than an invitation, correspond to her circumstances: cover letter, employment contract, and leave permission.
>
> **General required documents for a Spain Visa Application:**
>
> - [Download the application form](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/download-schengen-visa-application-form/), fill it completely and with sincerity. You can also fill the Spanish Visa application form electronically and then print a hard-copy. Learn how to fill-in the Spanish Visa application form!
> - 2 photos must be attached; the photo should be of passport format – a recent whole-face capture with a light background. Learn more about photo requirements and specifications for a Spanish Visa.
> - Your passport and copies of your previous visas – valid for at least 3 months beyond return date – are required. Your passport must have at least two blank pages.
> - A copy of your return-ticket reservation. It is not recommended to purchase the ticket before obtaining the visa – if not otherwise required
> - [Schengen Travel Insurance](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-insurance/) confirmation of minimum 30,000€ coverage within Spain and the entire Schengen area
> - A cover letter stating the purpose of visit to Spain and itinerary
> - [Flight Reservation](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/flight-itinerary-visa-application/) with dates and flight numbers specifying entry and exit from Spain
> - [Hotel Booking Reservation](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/proof-accommodation/) for the whole duration of the intended stay in Spain
> - Proof of civil status (marriage certificate, birth certificate of children, death certificate of spouse, ration card if applicable)
> - [Means of subsistence](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/means-subsistence/#Spain) –  Proof of sufficient financial means for the period of stay in Spain. A foreigner who seeks to enter the territory of Spain needs to attest owning the overall amount for duration up to 10 days that is representative of a 90% of the gross national minimum wage (598.68€) that is 583.74€, while in case of exceeding 10 days the daily required amount is 64.86€.
>
> **If employed:**
>
> - Employment contract
> - Current bank statement of the latest 6 months
> - Leave permission from employer
> - Income Tax Return (ITR) form or Certificate of Income Tax deducted at the source of salary